Is there a performance penalty with memory_order_relaxed?
On typical x86 and ARM systems, is there ever any performance penalty for making a variable std::atomic and only performing std::memory_order_relaxed operations? (Compared to making it a normal value and doing non-atomic operations.)
I'm aware that stronger memory ordering guarantees may result in performance penalties; I am specifically wondering if std::memory_order_relaxed imposes any penalty.
Also, let's assume the operations are being done on objects that satisfy std::is_always_lock_free. Otherwise, there'd surely be a penalty due to the required mutex.

it is still an atomic, RMW operations need to lock cache lines, etc ... also the compiler cannot optimize atomic writes,  writing to it twice is two writes.

Yeah, huge problems; it can't be optimized away so an atomic loop counter would prevent auto-vectorization and even loop unrolling.  And it can't even be kept in a register.   Same as volatile.  And as Ahmed says, things like ++ would become atomic RMWs, so even worse than volatile.

It also prevents compiler optimizations such as reloading the value instead of spilling the last read value on the stack when running out of registers, etc.

@AhmedAEK optimising two writes into one is allowed (and recommended) for atomics under the as-if rule. See https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4455.html

@MikeVine: But no compilers actually do even that minimal optimization, because of unsolved problems with cases where it could be undesirable. https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0062r1.html / Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes? .  And of course that's far from the biggest concern; not being able to keep the value in a register or do value-range analysis etc. etc. will have a much bigger worst-case impact for things like local variables used in loops.

Yes, there is generally a performance penalty. Not necessarily because of the underlying CPU architecture, but because of semantic constraints use of atomics imposes for the compiler.
If you replace an atomic variable with relaxed semantics with a non-atomic variable then this either doesn't affect the permitted observable behaviors of the program or it widens the set of permissible behaviors (e.g. because code paths become UB due to data races being introduced).
So, with the relaxed atomics the compiler is more constrained in what optimizations it can apply because it must assure a narrower set of observable behaviors.
The list of affected optimizations is long, as some comments under the question already hint at.
And additionally, as mentioned in the question comments, some relaxed operations, e.g. RMW, still differ from their non-atomic equivalents even on the ISA level for x86 and ARM.

there is always a performance penalty is slightly too strong.  A variable that's only accessed once in a function which doesn't inline (or only read then written), will probably compile to the same asm both ways.  As long as there aren't any adjacent objects the compiler could have merged the access with (e.g. arr[i] and arr[i+1] using AArch64 ldp load-pair, or just using a 64-bit access to store two 32-bit values)...  There are realistic cases where there's a variable or struct member you could make atomic-relaxed (like volatile in real compilers) without changing the asm.

@PeterCordes I meant the "always" as in independently of the architecture. That wasn't clear. I used a weaker adverb.
